# CSS background color not showing up

Tags: html, css

I know how to fix the below code to make text ccc background as red. But I need to understand why below code is not showing red background color.

```css
div.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
div.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">aa</div>
<div class="b">ccc</div>
```

Comment: Replace `div.a` with `.a` & `div.b` with `.b`

Comment: This should not make any difference in the given example. btw I know how to fix, but I would like to what is wrong with the above sample code

Comment: Removing `height` property should do. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3f9hy72u/).

Comment: I added many duplicates explaining different situation similar to yours. Follow them carefully and you will get everything about floating and why you have this behavior

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this is `float` CSS attribute and as mentioned by the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):

> The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still
>   remaining a part of the flow (in contrast to absolute positioning).

There are many ways to deal with this situation and fix the flow of items surrounding a floating element one of them mentioned by the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#Clearing_floats) too in clear section:

> Sometimes you may want to force an item to move below any floated
>   elements. For instance, you may want paragraphs to remain adjacent to
>   floats, but force headings to be on their own line. See clear for
>   examples.

```css
div.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
div.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a">aa</div>
<div class="b">ccc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

also in your case you have to add floating right to your `div.b` to fix the flow of `.b` element in the page:

```css
div.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
div.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a">aa</div>
<div class="b">ccc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

another way to is add display:inline-block too:

```css
div.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
div.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="a">aa</div>
<div class="b">ccc</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and another example:

```css
div.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
div.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="a">aa</div>
<br />
<div class="b">ccc</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that `div.a` is a float and so `div.b` needs to be defined. Just adding `float:left;` to `div.b` resolves it. The answer may vary depending on what you're trying to achieve though.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
div.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="a">aa</div>
<div class="b">ccc</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "needs to be defined"?

Comment: I found if I remove float from the first div it works ... and adding float to secound div like your solution it works but why ? what makes it invisible with one div float ?

Comment: Because, then `div.a` is blocking the view of `div.b` otherwise. Increase the height of `div.b` in that scenario (e.g., 400px) you will see what I mean.

Comment: I expected the text also be hidden because it is taken out of the normal flow of the document like absolute position

Comment: Text can just overflow in that situation. Try setting div.b width > div.a width it is the same as I was saying earlier.

Comment: yes I tried also I tried to switch float from left to right without adding float to second div the confusing part was in MDN definition of `float` vs `position absolute` they used the same words  ` when an element is floated it is taken out of the normal flow of the document`  || `absolute : The element is removed from the normal document flow` ...

Comment: while `absloute ` in this case will hide text `float` will not

Comment: @dxdc

then overflow:hidden should hide text.

div.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

Comment: @NabilRahiman there is no overflow as `Ma'moun othman` answer mention the main different between float and position absolute is that float even it removed from document flow it `still a part of document flow` where it makes text wrap around floated element rather than hidden behind it  like in position absolute

Answer (score 0):

There is a red background, but underneath the blue div. The red div is static, so it will be rendered under float elements, because of how stacking context works in CSS.

Comment: do you have any idea why text not hidden also ?

Comment: @bebwer, thanks, this is the kind of answer I am looking out for. I also would like to know why the text is hidden in that case

Answer (score 0):

You have floated the div.a to left ,  now it is floated and div.b gets under div.b

So if you want to set it properly, you must set your floated div.a into a parent div, then 
apply below given css to clear the space under the floated div.a.  , so that you can see your div.b

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body::after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
        
        div.a {
            height: 200px;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: blue;
            float: left;
        }
        
        div.b {
            height: 200px;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: red;
        }
        /* then go for parent of floated div (div.a) and set this property to clear floated area beneath the div.a --> */
        
        #parent:after {
            clear: both;
            display: block;
            content: "";
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- you must enclose the ddiv you want to float into another div  -->
    <div id="parent">
        <div class="a">aa</div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">ccc</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I like your solution as you didn't modify my css code snippet. But still wondering why the text is not hidden from viewing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
    div.a {
      height: 200px;
      width: 50%;
      background-color: blue;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    div.b {
      height: 200px;
      width: 50%;
      background-color: red;
float:left;
position:relative;

    }



<div class="a">aa</div>
<div class="b">ccc</div>
```